# ToolbarItemGroup(placement:.keyboard) show many button

Tags: swiftui

```
.toolbar(content: {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement:.keyboard) {
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    focus = false
                } label: {
                    Text("close").foregroundColor(Color.theme)
                }
            }
        })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91ctv.jpg)

I don't know why this is set up, but it displays normally on the emulator. On a real machine, however, multiple buttons are displayed

Which friend can answer it？thanks

Comment: How about using two `ToolbarItem`s? One for the spacer and one for the button?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't change

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.